# VBA: Calling a sub on another worksheet with multiple arguments

Tags: vba, excel

I've been struggling for a while to call a procedure (sub) with arguments that is located on another worksheet. I can call a procedure on another worksheet. I can call a procedure with arguments. But combining the two causes me headache's.

Here's what I have now:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Call Sheet2.FillCombo("Mngt Dashboard", "ComboMonth")
'Sheet2.FillCombo"Operational Dashboard", "ComboMonth2"
End Sub
```

I tried both syntaxis for calling the procedure but both result in 'subscript out of range (9)'.
Here's the procedure being called (located on sheet2):

```
Sub FillCombo(SheetName As String, ObjName As String)
Dim objCombo As Object
Set objCombo = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(SheetName).OLEObjects(ObjName).Object
objCombo.Clear
objCombo.AddItem.....
...
End Sub
```

Is there anyone out there that can show me the light?

Thanks in advance, Mark

Comment: The code is fine. That error means one of the arguments is wrong.

Comment: Can you make sure the name of the worksheet and of the combomonth are actually "Mngt Dashboard" and "ComboMonth"?

Comment: Also avoid using `ActiveWorkbook`.  For this case, specify the Workbook by name with `Workbooks(WORKBOOK_NAME)` or perhaps use `ThisWorkbook`.  It is possible that the workbook that contains 
"Mngt Dashboard" isn't the active workbook.

Comment: @MarkH could you call by only `FillCombo` rather than `Sheet2.FillCombo`? And, move the sub to a module?

Comment: I agree with both of the last two comments, especially the latter.  That is what modules are for.  Just say "Sheets(SheetName)" unless you are working between WorkBOOKS. 
As far as calling FillCombo, you won't need to specify Sheet2.  Just call FillCombo.  You should be able to have the same code on each sheet if you derive the SheetName and Month programmatically.
Lastly, it looks like you didn't post all your code, and there seems to be lacking a clearly defined "Question".

Comment: First of all: thanks for the replies. I managed to tackle the situation by moving the procedures into the module and remove the unnecessary prefixes.

At P J Roosenburg: For the sake of readability I left out the some of the code as I did not think I would be of any value.

Answer (score 1):

On Line 2, try dropping the parenthesis:

```
Sheet2.FillCombo "Mngt Dashboard", "ComboMonth"
```